# When to use quotation marks in pgAmin sql code

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

In the following sql statement (using pgAdmin 4): 
field_1 comes from table_1
field_2 comes from table_2
Why do I need to place field_1 in quotes, but not field_1? Is there a better way to write this query?

```
SELECT "field_1", field_2 FROM table_1 
INNER JOIN table_2 ON "field_1" = table_2.id
ORDER BY field_2
```

Comment: What is the actual column name of `field_1`? If you have to escape it with quotes, it's probably a reserved word.

Comment: @TheImpaler: "backticks" are illegal in SQL identifiers.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS